# Finding the range of $(a +\ 1)(a +\ 2b)$ for positive integers $a, b$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, factoring

Consider the problem of finding the range of the function $f(a, b) = a^2 + a + 2b + 2ab$ for all positive integers $a,\ b$. Factoring this, we find that $f(a, b)\ =\ (a +\ 1)(a +\ 2b)$. However, I can't think of an easy way to find what integer values this function can take on across all $a, b$.

Here is some work I've done so far:

- Observe that $a\ + 1$ and $a +\ 2b$ must have different parity; if $a + 1$ is odd, $a + 2b$ is even, and if $a + 1$ is even, then $a + 2b$ is odd. This implies $f(a,\ b)$ can only take on even integer values.
- Furthermore, if we let $(a\ + 1)(a\ +\ 2b) = k$, my idea was to view $k$ as its prime factorization. Because $a +\ 1$ and $a +\ 2b$ have different parity, one must be divisible by the highest power of $2$ that divides $k$. I feel like this leads to casework on which of the two terms is the even one.

I also wrote a computer program, and found that:

> It appears that $(a +\ 1)\(a +\ 2b)$ takes on all even integer values *except* those that are equal to twice a power of $2$. The smallest few values it takes on are `6, 10, 12, 14, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 66, 68, 70`.

Can anyone give me some insights into this specific problem, or to this class of problem in general? Thanks very much!

Comment: You could say "a power of $2$" rather than "twice a power of $2$", because, of course, twice any power of $2$ is just the next power of $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only observation missing from the question is that $a+1$ and $a+2b$ are both *greater than $1$*, one being odd and one being even. This means that in order to be written in this form, $k$ must have an even divisor (and so it cannot be odd) and a nontrivial odd divisor (and so it cannot be a power of $2$).

For any other number, we can factor $k = pq$, where $p$ is odd, $q$ is even, and $p>1$. (For example, we can take $q$ to be the highest power of $2$ dividing $k$, but we don't have to.) Then there are two cases:

1. If $p < q$, solve $a+1 = p$ and $a+2b = q$ for $a$ and $b$, getting $a = p-1$ and $b = \frac{q-p+1}{2}$. These are both positive integers, because $p>1$ and $q-p \ge 1$.
2. If $p > q$, solve $a+1 = q$ and $a+2b = p$ for $a$ and $b$ instead, getting $a = q-1$ and $b = \frac{p-q+1}{2}$. These are both positive integers, because $q>1$ and $p-q \ge 1$.

In both cases, we have written $k$ as $(a+1)(a+2b)$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$.